# How to read a CSV file using linq after the csv file is downloaded from Azure?

Tags: c#, linq, csv, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find an example of how to read a csv file using linq.  My problem is that the examples I have found so far, the csv file is stored on the local machine and I am pulling the csv file from azure.  Here is the example I found so far:

```
var stuff = from l in File.ReadLines(filename)
                            let x = l.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                     .Skip(1)
                                     .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                            select new
                            {
                                Sum = x.Sum(),
                                Average = x.Average()
                            };
```

The problem is in my pull from Azure, I have to use DownloadToStream and move the file to a MemoryStream.  When I have to work with MemoryStream, what should replace "File.ReadLines(filename)"?

Comment: Unless you have control over the code generating the CSV, you probably want a dedicated CSV lib for the parsing step. There are a lot more gotchas than you would think when it comes to CSV's

Comment: Take a look at [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - it can work on streams and handle CSV files.  It's in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace (and yes, it can be used by C# despite it's name).   See [TextFieldPaser Constructor (Stream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128082(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

Comment: For the TextFieldParser, can it also confirm the file is indeed a csv as opposed to a regular text file and any other pitfalls that might come up?  If not, could someone recommend a good csv library that could address these concerns and provides good performance?

Comment: @user1790300 - What do you mean confirm the file is indeed a CSV file?  Based on what criteria?

Comment: @Tim, Is there a way to confirm the format is indeed csv?

Comment: @user1790300 - I ask again, how do you confirm it"s a CSV file?  *What is the criteria?*  A CSV file is a text file that has rows (lines) of data with the fields separated by commas.  I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the data in a `Stream`, there are a lot of libraries that make reading CSV pretty easy. You'll want to avoid using `Split()`, because CSV is a bit more complicated than that and is easy to get wrong.

One library to do this with is the [Ctl.Data](http://ctl-global.github.io/data.html) NuGet package:

```
class MyPoco
{
    // CSV file must have a header with these property names.
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public DateTime Baz { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<MyPoco> Read(CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
        using(Stream s = blob.OpenRead())
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            foreach(MyPoco x in Ctl.Data.Formats.Csv.ReadObjects<MyPoco>(sr))
            {
                yield return x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(caveat: I'm the author of this package)

Comment: For your CSV libaray, can it also confirm the file is indeed a csv as opposed to a regular text file and any other pitfalls that might come up?

Comment: The library will throw an exception if the input is not valid CSV, and beyond just the format you can use annotation-based property validation to check that the input is within expected parameters.